SQL: How to return multiple columns from different tables in a query that links multiple tables through different fields
I have a SQL query that is written like this:
SELECT table1.`full_name`
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id IN 
    (SELECT table2.surname_id_id
     FROM table2
     WHERE table2.location_id_id IN 
         (SELECT table3.id,
          FROM table3
          WHERE table3.blood_type_id_id IN 
              (SELECT table4.id
               FROM table5
               INNER JOIN table4 ON table5.gender_id = table4.gender_id_id
               WHERE table5.dob IN ("dob1", "dob2"))))

I cannot change the structure of the database tables.
With this code, I can start with a list of dates of birth in the list I've given to table5, and it will give me back a set of full names in table 1, by linking information in various other tables together. This SQL query returns the set of full names, as expected.
However, what I actually want to return is various columns from different tables at the end. e.g. I don't just want the full name, I also want to return for example:
table2.middle_name
table2.maiden_name
table2.zip_code

table3.rhesus_group
table3.doctors_name

table4.phone_number

table5.birth_cert_provided

etc.
So at each stage, I want to add to a list of specified columns, and at the end, I expect the full names to be printed, along with a series of other information that I acquired through the SELECTs.
I tried to change the syntax to be SELECT * FROM table X i.e. select all information from every table as you pass through.
However I get an error:

SQL Error [1241] [21000]: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

which I understand is because I'm not being specific about the column I want passed to the next link.
If someone could explain how to link multiple tables together with various IDs, while passing multiple columns from each table through the query so my final table is a filtered table with multiple columns from different tables, I would appreciate it.

Please update your question with sample data for all the tables and the result you want to achieve - all as editable text formatted as tables. However, guessing what you’re trying to achieve, can’t you just join the tables?

Have you ever heard of JOIN?

Thanks - regarding JOIN, this is my first ever SQL query so i've heard of it in theory but not how to implement it. No problem for sample data, this is actual private data (not belonging to me) that's why i changed the table names, so I'll have to re-create an example from scratch which is no problem but just will take some time thanks.

Instead of a big WHERE clause you want to move all of these relationships into your FROM clause by way of JOIN/ON clauses so that you can pull these other table's columns in to your SELECT clause:
SELECT table1.`full_name`
   table2.middle_name,
   table2.maiden_name,
   table2.zip_code,
   table3.rhesus_group,
   table3.doctors_name,
   table4.phone_number,
   table5.birth_cert_provided
FROM table1
   INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table.surname_id_id
   INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.location_id_id = table3.id
   INNER JOIN table4 ON table3.blood_type_id_id = table4.id
   INNER JOIN table5 ON table4.gender_id_id = table5.gender_id
WHERE
    table5.dob IN ("dob1", "dob2")

